# Hotel Booking System (Room Available,(Buttons))

Tags: vb.net, button

I'm making a Hotel Booking System. I have 15 buttons representing each room. Once the date in has been selected, if a room has been booked, then I need the button with the number on it to turn red and cannot be selected. However, I also need the button to be red with the time in-between the date in and date out.

This is the code I have so far. I'm not really sure where to start.

```
 Dim date1 As DateTime = dtpDateIn.Value.Date
    Dim date2 As DateTime = dtpDateOut.Value.Date
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim BookingFound As String = False 
    MyConn = New OleDbConnection 

    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString 

    MyConn.Open() 

    str1 = ("Select * from BookingInformation where [Date In] >= '" & date1 & "' AND [Date Out] <= '" & date2 & "'") 

    '("SELECT * FROM [BookingInformation] WHERE [Date In] = #" & dtpDateIn.Value.Date & "#") 

    Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str1, MyConn) 
    dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader 

    While dr.Read() 
        BookingFound = True 

        strDateOut = dr("Date Out").ToString 
        strDateIn = dr("Date In").ToString 
        strRoomNumber = dr("Room Number").ToString 

        CmbRooms.Items.Remove(strRoomNumber)
    End While
    MyConn.Close() 
End Sub
```

Comment: what's wrong with your code?

Comment: If the date is between date-in and date-out, then it is >= Date-in and <= Date-out, and you can modify your SQL appropriately. Does that help?

Comment: This is what I have so far. I'm testing it with a combobox to see if it finds the room number to delete but it is still not work. I've edited the code above.

Comment: OK if I understand you correctly (it's still a bit early in the morning here) then you need to extend your SQL a bit. You have 4 cases to cover, which can be done in two SQL conditions: [either d1 or d2 is within the date range] or [d1 <= date-in AND d2 >= date-out]. A diagram would help, but I don't think I can do that in a comment.  
(The 4 cases are 2 overlaps, 1 entirely within, and 1 starts before and ends after.) The first condition covers the first three cases, 2nd condition the last one.
Hopefully there is enough there to get you on the right lines!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it will be a little easier if you collect all your room buttons into a list and order them by the room number. Ideally, the button name will be something like btnRoom01. If you make sure that any single digit numbers start with a zero, the method of ordering used in my sample will work. If not, you'll need to re-write it to your requirements.

create a form wide list -

```
Dim roomButtons As New List(Of Button)
```

Here's the code to collect the buttons

```
Private Sub AddButtonsToCollection()
    roomButtons.Clear()
    For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
        Dim btn As Button
        If ctl.GetType = GetType(Button) Then
            btn = CType(ctl, Button)
            If btn.Name.Contains("btnRoom") Then
                roomButtons.Add(btn)
                roomButtons = roomButtons.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name).ToList
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And your while loop should look something like this

```
While dr.Read()
    Dim bookingDateIn, bookingDateOut As Date
    BookingFound = True
    Date.TryParse(dr("Date Out").ToString, bookingDateIn)
    Date.TryParse(dr("Date In").ToString, bookingDateIn)
    Dim RoomNumber As Integer = CInt(dr("Room Number").ToString)
    If (bookingDateIn <= date2) And (bookingDateOut >= date1) Then
        roomButtons(RoomNumber - 1).BackColor = Color.Red
        roomButtons(RoomNumber - 1).Text = RoomNumber.ToString & vbCrLf & bookingDateIn.ToShortDateString & vbCrLf & bookingDateOut.ToShortDateString
    End If
End While
```