# Booking Rooms (Searching between two dates)

Tags: vb.net, button

I'm trying to search the database to find the dates selected in the datetimepickers (also the inbetween dates) and then remove the items from the combobox. However, there are no errors, just the data is still in the combobox once selected.

```
  Dim date1 As DateTime = dtpDateIn.Value()
    Dim date2 As DateTime = dtpDateOut.Value()
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim BookingFound As String = False 
    MyConn = New OleDbConnection 

    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString 

    MyConn.Open() 

    str1 = ("Select * from BookingInformation where [Date In] >= '" & date1 & "' AND [Date Out] <= '" & date2 & "'") 

    Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str1, MyConn) 
    dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader 

    While dr.Read() 
        BookingFound = True 

        strDateOut = dr("Date Out").ToString 
        strDateIn = dr("Date In").ToString 
        strRoomNumber = dr("Room Number").ToString 

        CmbRooms.Items.Remove(strRoomNumber)
    End While
    MyConn.Close()
```

Comment: What a *great chance* to learn how to use the debugger.  Start with a breakpoint and go from there.  BTW, you should never concat strings to make SQL queries.  Use parameters always.  You also probably want to strip the time from those dates.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You are better off focusing on one question rather than asking it numerous times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140189/hotel-booking-system-room-available-buttons